# WordPress Plugin or Woo-Commerce Extension

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want a Combo Pack facility in my Woo-commerce WordPress Site for this:- Let's say the dress costs 100, the ring 20 and the shoe 40 and the purse 10 the total price would be 170. The total combo would be sold as 150, so with 20 discount. Is there any extension or plugin is there for it?

Comment: http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles/
you can use this plugin but its paid

Comment: but will it provide the functionality to auto calculate amount of discount?

Answer (score -1):

You can use woo-commerce function like chained product or

Comment: I tried but its not justifying my need as in both the cases it showing facility to put Actual and Sale Price. I want that I will put the combo Price and it will calculate all the Product's Price in Combo itself and will show the amount of discount.